# Ordering of group elements in MultiplicationTable vs CosetTable in GAP

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, gap, finitely-generated, cayley-table

I construct a finitely presented discrete group $G$ in GAP, a normal subgroup $H\triangleleft G$ of finite index $N$, and the factor group $G/H$ of order $N$. Assume for simplicity that $G$ has two generators $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$. For each coset $[g_k]\in G/H$, I wish to construct the $N\times N$ matrices of the left-regular representation of $G/H$, i.e.,
$$
U_{ij}([g_k])=\delta_{[g_i],[g_k][g_j]},
$$
as well as the matrix
$$
A_{ij}(\gamma_\alpha)=\delta_{[g_j],[g_i][\gamma_\alpha]},
$$
for each generator $\gamma_\alpha$, $\alpha=1,2$. Here, $\delta_{[g],[g']}=1$ if $[g]=[g']$ and zero otherwise. For any $[g_k]$ and $\gamma_\alpha$, the matrices $U$ and $A$ commute.

To compute $U_{ij}([g_k])$, I use the Cayley table of $G/H$ obtained from `MultiplicationTable` (below, `GmodH:=FactorGroup(G,H);`):

```
N:=Order(GmodH);;
M:=MultiplicationTable(GmodH);;
U:=NullMat(N,N);;
for j in [1..N] do
    i:=M[k][j];;
    U[i][j]:=1;;
od;
```

where `k` ranges from $1$ to $N$ and denotes which $[g_k]$ I am considering.

To compute $A_{ij}(\gamma_\alpha)$, I use `CosetTable`:

```
CT:=CosetTable(G,H);;
A:=NullMat(N,N);;
for i in [1..N] do
    j:=CT[a,i];;    
    A[i,j]:=1;;
od;
```

where `a` ranges over $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_1^{-1},\gamma_2^{-1}$.

The problem is my matrices `U` and `A` do not commute, although they should, which I suspect is because the order of group elements in `MultiplicationTable` is not the same as the order of cosets in `CosetTable`.

Is there a better way to do this, such that the group elements are in the same order? I would like to avoid looping over group elements as much as possible, since my $N$ can get quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of `MultiplicationTable` is the ordering of the list of its `Elements`. This will depend on the way how the group is represented.

The ordering of the cosets in `CosetTable` is so that the table is standardized. This means that when reading it row by row, new cosets arise in the natural order of integers.

I think it will be easiest to avoid building the two tables, but just work with the transversal:

```
rt:=RightTransversal(G,H);
```

and then for an element $g$ (e.g. a representative from the transversal)

```
U:=NullMat(N,N);
A:=NullMat(N,N);
for i in [1..N] do
  A[i][PositionCanonical(rt,rt[i]*g)]:=1;
  U[PositionCanonical(rt,g*rt[i])][i]:=1;
od;
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason I wanted to use the tables (at least the coset table) is that $N$ can be very large (~$10^7$), and building big matrices in GAP element by element seems slow. My current approach to building $A$ is in fact to save the $4\times N$ coset table in a text file, and then build $A$ in Matlab as a sparse matrix. I was hoping to likewise save the $N\times N$ multiplication table and reconstruct the $U$ matrices (all $N$ of them) in Matlab as sparse matrices.

Comment: What specifically is slow? The `NullMat` command? Or the entry assignment? Clearly `MultiplicationTable` cannot be faster than building the matrix.